# what are the differences among mambaforge, mambaforge-pypy3, miniforge, miniforge-pypy3

Tags: python, pypy, mamba, mini-forge, mambaforge

there have been explanations about the different between `miniforge` and `miniconda`

> `miniforge` is the community (conda-forge) driven minimalistic conda installer. Subsequent package installations come thus from conda-forge channel.
> `miniconda` is the Anaconda (company) driven minimalistic conda installer. Subsequent package installations come from the anaconda channels (default or otherwise).

as for [mambaforge, mambaforge-pypy3, miniforge, miniforge-pypy3](https://conda-forge.org/miniforge/), how do we choose which package to install?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mamba* use the c/c++ implementation of the conda protocol "mamba" instead of the python implementation which is called conda. The *pypy3 variants ship with PyPy as the python implementation in the base environment instead of CPython.